# MySQL DB Column Not Updating after TinyMCE post INSERT

Tags: php, mysql, tinymce

I've managed to implement a simple TinyMCE editor on my site and have it call using mySQL database. My problem Im having now is getting the DB to overwrite the contents already stored inside with what is being posted?

I simply want to overwrite the table contents (within the column) with what is being inserted.

```
 Here is my code:

<!--- CONNECT TO THE DATABASE------>
 <?php
 $con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","jdkldk8%by");
 if (!$con)
  {
   die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
   }

 mysql_select_db("cms", $con);

 $sql="INSERT INTO tinymce (contents, contact, slider, resources)
 VALUES
 ('$_POST[contents]','$_POST[contact]','$_POST[slider]','$_POST[resources]')";

 if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
 {
 die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
   }
 echo "1 record added";
 mysql_close($con);
 ?>

 <!--- END DATABASE SETTINGS ----->
```

[ View your changes here ]

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

Well... i tried again but its still not posting all fields to the DB! only updating 1.

```
  <!--- CONNECT TO THE DATABASE------>
  <?php
    require_once('db.php');

   $contents=$_POST['contents']; 
   $contact=$_POST['contact']; 
   $slider=$_POST['slider']; 
   $resources=$_POST['resources'];
   $id='1'; 

   $sql="UPDATE tinymce SET `contents`='$contents', `contact`='$contact', `slider`='$slider', `resources`='$resources' WHERE id='$id'";

   if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
    {
   die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
     }
   echo "Saved!";
   mysql_close($con);
    ?>

  <!--- END DATABASE SETTINGS ----->
```

Comment: you can either delete the old record and then insert a new record, or use an update statement: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html

Comment: You should use prepared statements, or at least quote values to insert properly. Obligatory link: http://bobby-tables.com/ Also, php's `mysql` package is deprecated, use `mysqli` instead (or pdo).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use UPDATE, not INSERT, to update a previously created MySQL column.

Try editing a column using phpmyadmin and copying the resulting code from their MySQL code viewer.

Comment: thanks... i gave it a try. However, i am now getting this reply from the server:

Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(contents, contact, slider, resources) VALUES ('','

Comment: ok so I updated my code a little bit and it updates, however, it updates one field and clears the others. For xample, if I add a change using TINYMCE and post that change, the other text areas become blank but the updated field is up-to-date and posted. PLEASE HELP!!!!!!!!!!  (I UPDATED MY CODE WITH THE CHANGED CODE ABOVE)